# Regex как распарсить строку

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Всем привет,есть вот такая строка:

```
const html = '<div class="ssr-detail-item active ">
                <div class="icon-container">
                    <svg class="svg-icon icon" name="icon-tick-package">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-tick-package">
                    </use>
                    </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="label">1 piece of cabin baggage<span class="separator">, </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

             <div class="ssr-detail-item active ">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <svg class="svg-icon icon" name="icon-tick-package">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-tick-package">
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="label">20 Kg Baggage<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ssr-detail-item active ">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <svg class="svg-icon icon" name="icon-tick-package">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-tick-package">
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="label">Standard Seat Selection<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ssr-detail-item active ">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <svg class="svg-icon icon" name="icon-tick-package">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-tick-package">
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="label">Sandwich<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ssr-detail-item">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <div class="icon">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="label">Refund/Reissue without Penalty
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ssr-detail-item active lastActive">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <svg class="svg-icon icon" name="icon-tick-package">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-tick-package">
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="label">In-Flight Entertainment<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>';
```

Как можно отсюда получить массив текста из `<div class="label">`, при условии что у родителя есть класс active чисто на js,без библиотек и т.д. ,кто шарит?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

собственно тут в самой регулярке видимо вопрос.
вот так она будет выглядеть примерно
https://regex101.com/r/hZuYWi/1

а по js все просто

```
let a='наш html';
const regStr=/тут та длинная регулярка/gs; //ключи именно gs
const res = a.match(regStr);
console.log(res);
```

ЗЫ по концовке регулярки, почему там span или div. Это на случай если div с текстом "Refund/Reissue without Penalty" может становится тоже active.
Вобщем работает, но есть нюансы ))

Comment: регулярка вернула масив div`oв с класами active,а как сделать чтобы был масив текстов,что лежит в <div class="label">

Comment: let a='наш html';
const regStr=/тут та длинная регулярка/gs; //ключи именно gs
const res = [...html.matchAll(regStr)];
res.forEach(el => console.log(el[1]));

вот так выведет только текст в Label. Все время забываю, что в js match иначе робит ))

Comment: работает,спасибо)